# \n is not formatting well in jspdf and jspdf-autotable

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am creating a PDF from javascript data that comes from an API.

Everything works right but I have a problem with data that comes with a `\n` new line:

- If the column `halign` is set to `left`, data fills the cell and is readable, but `\n` new lines are omitted.
- If the column `halign` is set to `center`, `\n` are not omitted but data is overwritting in some lines.

It is like autotable calculates the raw data cell space: if it's set to `halign` `left` due to it omitting the `\n` it is shown rigth but without linebreaks, if `halign` is set to `center`, due to respecting `\n` new lines, vertical space increases and text overwrites itself due to presetted cell space.

I have tried adding `overflow: 'linebreak'` but it seems it is not resolving the problem.
I could also try to divide text in some tables if a `\n` is found, but the table is big and it would break the structure, as it includes images in some cells, paging, logo, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+pdf+newlines+halign+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.